# Codeigniter Use of undefined constant SITE_NAME error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter is writing this error in the logs: "Use of undefined constant SITE_NAME - assumed 'SITE_NAME' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)".

Here's my code :

```
<a class="navbar-brand mr-1" href="<?php echo site_url('backend') ?>"><?php echo SITE_NAME ?></a>
```

What does it mean and why am I seeing it?

Comment: What is your CI version? Have you hacked the core code at all?  Where/How are you trying to access this constant?  Is this constant declared in your config file?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't specify site_name in config.php.